# Cloud Code Not able to find users installations on Parse database

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, push-notification

I have a Friends table that contains userIds for a user list of friends. The user column is a pointer to the User table and the friendId does the same.

I'm attempting to find all of the users that equal the "friendId" for a particular user and send notifications to those users.

I've added a "user" column to my Installations table which is a pointer to "User" so that I can find my installations for specific users and send a push notification.

The issue I am having is I an unable to link those queries together to get send my push notifications to my list of friends.

Any suggestions are helpful.

My current cloud code

```
    Parse.Cloud.define("pushCheckIn", function(request, response) {
// Find users near with pending messages

var friendList = Parse.Object.extend("Friends");
var username = request.params.username;
var location = request.params.location;
var userQuery = new Parse.Query(friendList);

userQuery.equalTo("friendId", Parse.User);

// Find devices associated with these users
var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.matchesQuery("user", userQuery);

var alertMsg = username + " checked-in at " + location;

Parse.Push.send({
  where: pushQuery,
  data: {
    alert: alertMsg,
    sound: "beep-shinymetal.caf",
    title: alertMsg
  }
}, {
  success: function() {
    response.success(alertMsg);
    // Push was successful
  },
  error: function(error) {
    response.error("push failed");
  }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description of your tables is complicated and I don't fully understand, however I think that `new Parse.Query(friendList);` should rather be `new Parse.Query("Friends");` and `userQuery.equalTo("friendId", Parse.User);` doesn't make sense at all, if it is string you should use `userQuery.equalTo("friendId", yourFriendIdString);`

If you try to explain your tables better, I can try to give you better advice :)

Answer (score 0):

The Installations table can not be queried directly without using the master key. To query the installations table, use

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

before executing the query

Comment: OK that definitely helped me get the readers ok..I think I see one of my problems is that the objects returned from my query of the users friends can't be used as is. My though would be to just select the userid's of those friends and then use them in the installation query...need to figure that out in javascript

Comment: Have you executed just the userQuery and checked that you do indeed get a list of users? I can't see why this would not work, as long as both "friendId" and "user" are pointer columns.

Comment: Yes I get my list of users as expected. I'm just not sure how to articulate that set of results and query for the installations in Javascript to send my notifications

Comment: It seems correct to me. Have you tried to just execute the pushQuery and see if you're left with a list of installations?